# Transformation of logarithmic function & scaling

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, physics, curve-fitting

So I need to do this:

Define a suitable fitting function, "Planck(l, *p)" to the experimental data of the Planck function. This function is to be based on the Planck formula:

```
Bλ(T) = (2hc^2/l^5) / (exp(hc/klt) -1)
```

, where **l** is the set of wavelengths, **k** is Boltzmann’s constant, **h** is Planck’s constant and **c** is the speed of light.
I need to have 2 fitting parameters in **p**, one will be **T** (temperature) and the other is going to be a scaling factor.

I plotted out the experimental data and the fitting function for a **T** which I found through trial-and-error so that its peak is equal to the data's peak and this is my result:
[image: plot]
So apparently, I somehow need to transform the blue function in order for it to fall onto the experimental data, supposedly via the scale factor. What is a scale factor and how can I use it to move the whole graph 5 units to the right?
This is a logarithmic plot so things like `y=x^2 ==> y=(x-5)^2` **won't work**.
Any ideas please?

I am using `curve_fit` to fit the data.

Comment: Adding or subtracting in a log scale is the same as multiplying or dividing in a linear scale. That should be enough of a hint.

Comment: I know right! But the graph still doesn't move at all...

Comment: "*I am using curve_fit to fit the data*" vs "*fitting function for a T which I found through trial-and-error*". Care to elaborate? And did you actually consider the problem specification? You need a `T` and an `l`. I'm guessing your plot is about a manually fitted `T` for a given value of `l`. (This seems to be an easy problem, I just don't want to spoil your fun doing your homework.)

Comment: Sure! My function is dependent on l (wavelength) and p which has 2 parameters, temperature and scaling factor.
I first need to make a rough guess of these parameters and I found (roughly) the value of T by matching the height of the peaks. Now I need to find the scaling factor but I really don't know how this works. Once i make a guess, I use curve_fit for the exact parameters.

Comment: What makes you think that you "*first need to make a rough guess of these parameters*"? I mean, you shouldn't have to be *too* specific for `curve_fit` to work. Have you tried fitting both the scaling factor and `T` at the same time? What do you expect? What did you get instead?

Comment: To move it left or right, I'd expect there to be another parameter, that subtracts/adds to `l`, before any operators/functions are applied to it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am not really sure about how does the scaling factor work. I am trying to put different values to it so I can see the resulting plot but I can't detect any pattern. I'll try writing the code from the beginning.

Comment: @jashandeep-sohi and also nikfilippas: a scaling factor *scales* the data. Scaling usually means *multiplying by a factor*. Now, try to piece this together with the comment by Mark Ransom right below your question:)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I know how to do this but I'm getting errors. For example, I've defined an array p with 2 elements which I also use in the function and I've defined the function to use the p[1] element of the array which is supposedly the scale factor. But I've getting error: Tuple index out of range. And I don't know how could this be since all my arguments are within range.

Comment: Without some specifics it's hard to tell your exact problem. An error is a good start. Include your code and the corresponding error in your question, accompanied by what the expected output was. (You should also check `len(p)`, it's probably not what you think it is.) Also: `p` should probably be a list, not a tuple.

Answer (score -1):

To get the shift of the curve along the log plot of the x-axis, you can scale the x-axis parameter by a constant.  That is, use `b*L` in place of `L` and treat `b` as a free parameter in your fit.

For this particular problem, typically one knows the wavelength in absolute terms (though I can imagine situations where this isn't the case, like an uncalibrated sensor, moving sources, etc) and it doesn't make sense to scale it, especially by more than 10x.  If it's the case that you know the wavelength but you still get the shifted plot, **you probably have the units wrong for the wavelength** since this will result in a similar shift.  This may not be the case, but it's a common mistake that would lead to such a shift.

Scaling the x-axis parameter or changing the units will both shift curve along a log axis because `log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)`.  Overall, though the log on the x-axis is an unnecessary confusion, and it seems that your data is taken with linear spacing anyway, so if you're having trouble, it might be best to first get this working while plotted on a linear axis before working on the log version (maybe just working with the part near the peak).

To call the above a "shift" though is confusing because it's only a shift in the pictorial sense and is not a shift of the fit or the function.  Instead, by the substitution `b*L` for `L`, one distorts the function, but in a way to match the distortion of the log axis, so it's only a shift of the picture, not the function.  The general way to shift a function is to add a term to the argument, so `f(x)` because `f(x+c)`, and this always works.

Finally, the way the axes are labelled in the original figure is confusing.  For example, I initially read the x-axis just as "Wavelength(um)".  To take the `log` of a number, the number must be unitless, so it would be more accurate to label the axis something like `log(L/1um)`, or something like that.

Comment: This is a very wrong answer. `f(x+c)` will shift the graph of `f` to the left with constant `c` on a linear plot, but `log(f(x+c))` will **NOT** be the shifted version of `log(f(x))`, it will be distorted. As to the mathematics: `log(x+c)` is **NOT** equal to `log(x)log(c)`! The point we tried to make was this: if you want to *shift the graph of log(f(x)) by a constant*, you need to **multiply** `f(x)` with a constant, for `log(c*f(x))=log(f(x))+c'` where `c'=log(c)`. We just didn't want to spell this out to homeworky OP.

Comment: Note that my previous comment referred to shifts along `y`, but the same can be said in the `x` direction on a log-log plot. So: `log(f(log(x)))`, the log-log plot, can be shifted, in general, by `log(c1*f(log(c2*x)))=log(c1*f(log(x)+log(c2)))=log(f(log(x)+log(c2))+log(c1)`.

Comment: You're free to add a proper solution, it's just a matter of taste of what each of us think is acceptable for a homework question. I wouldn't take action against that, Ijust tried to explain why we're hinting and not answering. My issue is with the shifting part. Sure, `f(x+c)` will shift, but as you can see in the image the *shape* of the fitting function is correct on the `log` scale, so you would need to shift it properly to maintain a good fit. (I have physical reasons as well to believe this, there's not much room to play around with the wave length.)